# How to tell LUIS that "April" is a name and not a month

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I have several patterns for finding information about people including things like:

`What is {personName} phone number`

and

`Tell me about {personName} in {Department}`

(Department being a custom entity)

However, no matter what kind of training I give it, *including* specific mentions of things like "April in Marketing", it always comes back with "April" being a datetimeV2 entity.

Is there a way I can force it to recognize that, within the name patterns, the string "April" is always a name, not "XXXX-04" datetimeV2 entity?

(We have no other people here with names the same as months, but I have to assume if we did, we'd need a workaround for those as well.)

Comment: Prebuilt entities are automatically extracted, what you can do is to have an ML entity "person" with a required featue pf personName prebuilt entity and label your utterance as such. this way "April" will be both recognized as person and datetime andyou can pick what you want and discard the other.

Comment: @MagedRefaat Thanks. I did a static list with "April" in it and it worked, but I like your idea of a ML with personName so I don't hit other snags in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix for now, Instead of a Simple Entity called personName in the Patterns, create a Pattern. Any entity (Go to Entities  Create, will be one of the options), and put that entity whatever you call it (personNameAny) and put it in the pattern, and it will achieve the scenario you want where personNameAny acts as a placeholder for whatever text that happens after words like “what is” put in the utterance. This comes with drawbacks and isn’t the optimum solution but it can cover a lot of scenarios.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-add-entities